# Joomla on EC2 instance: Where do the files go?

Tags: joomla, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

This a very simple question, but I haven't found the answer anywhere.

I am thinking about moving one of my websites, a joomla website, to the cloud, more specifically to a EC2 instance on Amazon. I have been watching some videos and the process seems rather simple. However, I haven't found any information about where the files are stored.

Are they in a S3 bucket? Are they saved somewhere else? How do I access the files?

Can I use Cloudfront to serve images and other files?

How does the whole integration process between EC2, S3 and Cloudfront work for a hosted website?

Thank you!

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience With EC2, you interact with the instance just as you would with any headless server in the basement. You can connect over SSH and install software, store files, etc, as normal.

It's great if you want a whole server to play with, but if it's just website hosting you're after, it might be overkill.

S3 can serve up static pages, but you can't install any code on there.

I don't know about cloudfront.

It seems to be though that what you need is standard website hosting.